# Accessing values from an array of structures

Tags: arrays, string, struct, structure

I'm trying to use an array of a the structure 'sommet', as defined below.

```
typedef struct sommet {
double x;
double y;
char nom[100];
struct arete2* voisin;};

sommet* somtab = (sommet *) calloc(nbnoeud, sizeof(sommet));
if(somtab = NULL){
    puts("Calloc error");
    exit(1);
}
```

In my code I have three separate arrays, xtab, ytab and nomtab, that respectively contain the x, y, and nom values for the somtab element of equivalent index (i.e. somtab[0].x = xtab[0], somtab[1].x = xtab[1] etc.) When come to set each of the somtab elements my programme breaks down and I never make it to "check3"

```
puts("check1");

for(a=0; a<nbnoeud; a++){
    printf("Read item %d; \t \t \t %s - (%lf, %lf). \n", a, nomtab[a], xtab[a], ytab[a]);
}

puts("check2");

for(a=0; a<nbnoeud; a++){
    somtab[a].x = xtab[a];
    somtab[a].y = ytab[a];
    strcpy(somtab[a].nom, nomtab[a]);
}

puts("check3");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a pointer to a pointer.

```
sommet** somtab = malloc(nbnoeud*sizeof(sommet));
```

use

```
    somtab[a]->x = xtab[a];
    somtab[a]->y = ytab[a];
    strcpy(somtab[a]->nom, nomtab[a]);
```

Comment: when I change the code to the above suggestion, it fails to compile, suggesting I convert it back to the original code. Surely calloc should return the address of the first byte of the array but when accessing individual elements it should revert to the passing by value.

error C2232: '->sommet::x' : left operand has 'struct' type, use '.'
error C2819: type 'sommet' does not have an overloaded member 'operator ->'

Comment: Having made both the suggested changes above, it still crashes out before 'check3'.